# Find longest palindrome by reversing substring

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to find the longest palindrome. I have two pointers starting at the first letter of the string. For each letter in the outer loop, I go through all the other letters in the inner loop and use the substring which is the difference between the starting letter(outer loop) and the ending letter(inner loop). I reverse this substring and check if the reversed version is the same as the original version. With that, I know I have found a palindrome. This algorithm is working for most of my test cases except one, and I can't figure out why.

```js
function longestPalindrome (str) {
  const string = str.toLowerCase();
  if (str.length < 2) return null;
  let palindrome = '';

  function stringReverser (start, end) {
    const reversed = string.substr(start, end).split('').reverse().join('');
    return reversed;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= string.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j <= string.length; j++) {
      if (string.substr(i, j) === stringReverser(i, j)) {
        if (string.substr(i,j).length > palindrome.length) {
          palindrome = string.substr(i,j);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (!palindrome) return null;
  return palindrome;
}

let result1 = longestPalindrome('My mom is called annnna')
let result2 = longestPalindrome('My dad is a racecar athelete')
let result3 = longestPalindrome('That trip with a kayak was quite an adventure!')

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
console.log(result3)// should return ' kayak ' but returns 't t' instead.
```

Comment: just a point of interest .. `string.substr(i,j).length` really? isn't that just `j` ?

Comment: You may want to use the `substring` method instead of `substr`. The former's second argument is the ending index, which looks like what your `j` is supposed to be, whereas the latter's is the number of characters to pull after the starting index. If you make that change, your code will work as is, and returns `" kayak "` for the third test.

Comment: @JaromandaX it's `<= j`

Comment: oh, yeah, the logic for the j loop is complete rubbish, isn't it

Comment: why @KimHogeling? then `a racecar a` would not be considered ... and `a man a plan a canal panama` would have no palindrome found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake in the original implementation is that `substr` arguments are `(begin, length)`, where the original code appears to have a mistaken assumption about the meaning of the second argument. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Here is a small change to your example code, which has more correct output:

```js
function longestPalindrome (str) {
  const string = str.toLowerCase();
  if (str.length < 2) return null;
  let palindrome = '';

  function stringReverser (start, length) {
    const reversed = string.substr(start, length).split('').reverse().join('');
    return reversed;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= string.length - i; j++) {
      if (string.substr(i, j) === stringReverser(i, j)) {
        if (j > palindrome.length) {
          palindrome = string.substr(i,j);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (!palindrome) return null;
  return palindrome;
}

let result1 = longestPalindrome('My mom is called annnna')
let result2 = longestPalindrome('My dad is a racecar athelete')
let result3 = longestPalindrome('That trip with a kayak was quite an adventure!')

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
console.log(result3)// should return ' kayak ' but returns 't t' instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest abstracting out the selected substring, and also using an `isPalendrome` function:

```
function longestPalindrome (str) {
  const inputString = str.toLowerCase();
  if (str.length < 2) return null;
  let longestPalindrome = '';

  function isPalendrome(strParam) {
    return strParam === strParam.split('').reverse().join('');
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= inputString.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j <= inputString.length; j++) {
      const thisStr = inputString.slice(i, j);
      if (!isPalendrome(thisStr)) continue;
      if (thisStr.length > longestPalindrome.length) longestPalindrome = thisStr;
    }
  }
  return longestPalindrome || null;
}

let result1 = longestPalindrome('My mom is called annnna')
let result2 = longestPalindrome('My dad is a racecar athelete')
let result3 = longestPalindrome('That trip with a kayak was quite an adventure!')

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
console.log(result3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using array helpers. The palindrome helper function checks if a given word is a palindrome. The filter looks for those that return true and then uses reduce to find the longest palindrome.

```
function findLongest(str) {
  let arr = str.split(' ').filter(word => palindrome(word));
  return arr.reduce((a,b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
}

function palindrome(str) {
    return str === str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

console.log(findLongest('That trip with a kayak was quite an adventure!'));
```

Comment: `My dad is a racecar athelete` ... doesn't return `a racecar a`

Comment: Ah, interesting stipulation. Missed that requirement.

Comment: Your code also misses `annnna` in the first example and returns `mom` instead? `a > b ? a : b` is not checking the length at all

Comment: yep, forgot to do comparisons on length. Was an oversight and is fixed now. This one was fun to take a stab at. Nice question.

Answer (score 0):

***Java Code***

"findlongestPalindrome" function takes parameter as string and return longest palindrome string

"isPalindrome" validates if the string is palindrome

public class findlongestPalindrome {

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("-->" + findlongestPalindrome("That trip with a kayak was quite an adventure!"));
      }
      public static String findlongestPalindrome(String s){
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          int len = 0;
          int maxlen = 0;
          String maxString = "";

          char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
          for(int i=0;i<=s.length();i++){
              for(int j=i;j<s.length();j++){
                  System.out.print(arr[j]);
                  sb.append(arr[j]);
                  if(isPalindrome(sb.toString())) {
                      len = sb.toString().length();
                      if(len > maxlen) {
                          maxlen = len;
                          maxString = sb.toString() + "";
                      }
                  }
              }
              sb = new StringBuffer();
              System.out.println();
          }
          return maxString;
      }
      public static boolean isPalindrome(String s){
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
          return sb.reverse().toString().equals(s);
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```js
function palendrom(str){
  let data = str.split(" ")
  let res = [];
  for(let a=0; a<data.length; a++){
    let rev = '';
    let subStr = data[a];
    for(let i = subStr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
      rev += subStr[i]
    }
     rev === subStr ? res.push(subStr) : "";
    }
  return res.reduce((acc, item)=> acc.length > item.length ? acc : item, '')
} 
console.log(palendrom("RajaR ama test"))
```

```js
function palendrom(str){
  let data = str.split(" ")
  let res = [];
  for(let a=0; a<data.length; a++){
    let rev = '';
    let subStr = data[a];
    for(let i = subStr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
      rev += subStr[i]
    }
     rev === subStr ? res.push(subStr) : "";
    }
  return res.reduce((acc, item)=> acc.length > item.length ? acc : item, '')
} 
console.log(palendrom("That trip with a kayak was quite an adventure!"))
```